# Will the REST-Interface be supported in the future

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api, project-server, ms-project

for an upcoming project, I will need to write a middleware that inserts some data into MS Project - Projects. After investigating I found two ways of communication with the Sharepoint-Ecosystem that I'd consider using:

- .NET API (CSOM - Libraries)
- REST Webservice

Figuring out the REST Webservice, especially the authentication took some time but I am now able to not only GET data but also make POST requests that update project fields.

While exploring the REST-paths I found myself surprised that they are actually much more developed than the sparse / rather confusing documentation had me believe.

**Question:** Will the MS Sharepoint / MS Project REST API be further developed or at least supported by Microsoft? I'd really like to use REST but I am not 100% confident that using the API will be the more future-proof choice.

**Edit:** I am aware that REST is not MS technology. The emphasis of my question is on the "Is Microsoft planning to change it's APIs or maybe discontinue REST support in future Sharepoint versions"

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: ♦ If an answer was helpful could you remove your question from the SO unanswered list, by marking it as answered, tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is future proof (until technology X replaces it, just like REST replaced others)

REST is **not** Microsoft Technology. It is the protocol almost all APIs use.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

**Edit:** Future Proof is mainly a software architecture issue

So you **do not** sprinkle you code with

```
context.httpClient.get( .. )
```

all over the place

But use one class/function

```
getContent(){
  return  context.httpClient.get( .. )
}
```

That way you have abstracted your code, can work with other data retrieval methods (like getting data from a localStorage cache) and it is easier to test.

#### And Microsofts'commitment

PnP Core JS is all about abstracting the REST interface for you

https://dev.office.com/patterns-and-practices

Comment: I am aware that REST is no Microsoft technology ;)
I'll change my question accordingly.

Comment: Danny, do you know if Microsoft are developing on the REST API? I think the feature support is still less than JSOM

Comment: Follow all the work Patrick Rodgers does on PnPCoreJS: https://gitter.im/OfficeDev/PnP-JS-Core

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman isn't `pnp-js-core` just an client-side interface for the REST api? I'm curious about the API itself

Comment: Yes, it abstracts the REST API, actively development bij Microsoft and used for many SPFx examples. Not likely to be discontinued soon

Comment: That is really great, but I'm still only curious about the actual REST API. Have you any source about it being improved? I haven't noticed much the last years

Comment: They have strong focus on SPFx, but JSOM won't be loaded by default (but is loadable for the things you can't do with REST), so I expect more REST functionality once SPFx is common ground... which (IMHO) could be 2018.  https://dev.office.com  is the site to follow

Comment: I shouldn't have mentioned jsom, my point was that even old jsom have more functionality than REST (AFAIK, e.g., taxonomy). A lot of features have been added silently, but not things like item version support

Comment: If you need something, bug, harass, complain to Patrick on Gitter